# Using option --array as an argument in slurm

Tags: slurm

Is it possible to use the `--array` option as an argument? I mean, I have a R code where I use arrays. The number of arrays depends of the file on which I execute my R code. I would like to pass as argument the number of arrays into the `sbatch my_code.R` command line , in order to never modify my slurm code : for example, for a file with 550.000 columns, I will need 10 arrays, a file with 1.000.000 columns will needed 19 arrays etc. I must get something like this "sbatch --array 1-nb_of_arrays_needed my_code.R" . The goal is to make my code usable by everyone, without the user needs to go into the slurm code in order to change the line `#SBATCH --array=x-y`

My R code (I don't show it in full) :

```
data<-read.table(opt$file, h=T, row.names=1, sep="\t")+1

ncol=ncol(data)
nb_arrays=ncol/55000
nb_arrays=round(nb_arrays)
opt$number=nb_arrays

...
```

Bests

Comment: Have you tried `sbatch --array 1-nb_of_arrays_needed my_code.R` ? This should work.

Comment: I will try. But do I need to define the line `#SBATCH --array=x-y` in my slurm code?

Comment: Not if you specify it through the command line.

Comment: `nb_of_arrays_needed` can be a variable ? I mean, I really want that `nb_of_arrays_needed` stays like this is the command line (I don't want to replace it by a number) . And this variable would change according to the size of the file I work on.

Comment: If it is in command line, it can be a Bash variable: `sbatch --array 1-$nb_of_arrays_needed my_code.R`. Note the dollar

Comment: Ok I know what you mean. But I don't know how to make the link between my R code and my Slurm code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your R script will start only when the job is scheduled. To be scheduled, it must be submitted, and to be submitted, it must know the argument to  `--array`.

So you have two options:

Either split your R script into to, one part that will run before the job is submitted, and the other that will run when the job starts. The first part will compute the necessary number of jobs in the array (and possibly submit the job array automatically) and the other part will do the actual calculations.

If you prefer having only one R script, you can differentiate the behaviour based on the presence or absence of `SLURM_JOB_ID` variable in the environment. If it is not present, compute the number of jobs and submit, if it is present, do the actual calculations.

The other option is to set `--array` in the submission job to a large value, and when the first job in the array starts, it computes the number of jobs that are necessary, and cancels the superfluous jobs.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I guess I will set a large number of arrays (up to 50, I will never need more than this value, I hope..).